# ¿Como guardar valor echo en mysqli?

Tags: php

soy nuevo en esto, como puedo guardar un echo en mysqli de codigo aleatorio que me da error

```
<?php
    $caracteres = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $desordenada = str_shuffle($caracteres);
    $CH = substr($desordenada, 1, 7);
?>

<label>Codigo Aleatorio</label>
<input type="text" id="codigo" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $CH ?>" />

<br><br>
<label>Nombres</label>
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
```

y el codigo que registra lo tengo asi

```
$codigo = $_POST ['codigo'];

$nombre = $_POST ['nombre'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO codigo (codigo,nombre) VALUES ('$codigo',$nombre')";

$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

como haria para guardarlo en la base de datos mysqli

Comment: ¿Lo que has hecho no funciona? ¿Cuál es el problema o mensaje de error que obtienes?

Comment: los campos estan dentro de un form???

Comment: Hay un mal cierre en la consulta SQL. $nombre no inicia con la comilla simple. Es muy probable que se esté parando ahi tu código

Comment: ya corregi el form y la comilla que falta, pero igual dice error, lo que quiera es guardar el caracter en la base de datos

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/frRwWQja#P1_nmPpGRb1AVi_l_KFp86d5L0zvK3reaA1GxG7QrEY
Aqui esta el codigo con base de datos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

intenta poner los inputs dentro de un `form` de esta forma:

`<form action="accion.php" method="post">`
`<label>Codigo Aleatorio</label>`
`<input type="text" id="codigo" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $CH ?>" />`

`<br><br>`
`<label>Nombres</label>`
`<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">`
`<button type="submit">Enviar</button>`
`</form>`

con eso deberías poder obtener los valores mediante el método post y guardarlos en tu  base de datos

Comment: Hola. esto pudo ser un comentario, no se sabe si omitio el codigo del form o le hace falta o si esta enviado por ajax los datos ... por lo cual no necesitaria un form. recuerda siempre aclarar el escenario con el OP antes de dar una respuesta prematura, saludos

Comment: Hay un mal cierre en la consulta SQL. `$nombre` no inicia con la comilla simple. Es muy probable que se esté parando ahi tu código.

Comment: @Jakala tu comentario debería ir en la pregunta, no en esta "respuesta".

Comment: Sorry, pensaba que era la pregunta 

Comment: voy a  probar este codigo

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 tienes razón, es mi primer comentario, gracias por tu observación